# ARIMA modelling: identifying p, q and P, Q from ACF and PACF plots

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, model-selection

[image]

I am conducting research using SARIMA models in my analysis. I have transformed my data to achieve stationarity (first difference and seasonal difference) and my ACF and PACF are as below. However, I have a challenge in identifying the values of p, q, P and Q. Any suggestions for these values?

The data is as follows:

```
Monthly Temp
25.3
25.2
25.4
23.3
22
21.5
21.4
21.1
24.2
24.8
23.2
23.8
25.8
28
26.2
23.6
22.1
20.8
21.5
23.4
23.9
26
23.1
23.3
24.4
26.6
27.6
25.1
23.6
22.2
22
22.1
25.5
26.7
24.2
25.2
25.9
26.9
26.6
24
22.7
21.8
21.5
21.5
23.1
25.4
23
23
23.8
24.3
25.9
22.7
22.6
21.1
20.4
20.7
23.3
23.9
22.7
23.5
23.8
25.8
24.2
23.4
23.5
22.2
22.2
21.2
24.6
25.3
22.8
23.1
25.5
27.7
27.2
24.7
23.1
22.7
20.7
22.3
24.8
25.9
23.6
23.3
24.8
27.2
27.1
25
23.3
22.2
21.1
20.6
23.6
24.8
22.9
23.1
22.6
23.6
25.4
25.1
24.4
21.9
21.4
22.3
24.8
25.6
23.8
23.4
25.9
26.9
26.5
24.4
22.8
22.6
21.3
21.6
24
25
22.9
23.1
24.9
26.2
24.4
24
23.2
23.3
21.1
22.3
24.4
24.5
23.6
23.3
25.7
26.8
26
24.3
23
21.3
20.7
22.5
24.7
25.9
22.8
24.3
26.5
28.1
27.2
24
22.6
21.9
21.8
23.1
25.6
23.4
22.3
22.7
23.4
25
25.2
24.7
23.3
22.3
19.7
20.2
23.7
25.6
23.5
24.9
25.9
27.4
26.1
23.5
23.2
22.6
21.6
21.8
24.1
25.4
22.9
22.3
24.7
27.2
27.1
25.4
23.8
22.4
22.2
22.8
24.5
25.9
25.4
25.5
23.3
25.4
24.9
23.5
23.1
21.8
20.8
23.2
25.2
25.4
22.8
23.6
25.5
26.9
25.1
24.4
23.3
21.9
22.8
21.5
24.6
25
23.6
23.4
25.1
27.4
27
25.9
24.8
23.4
22.7
23.3
25.1
27
24.8
25.9
25.2
25.4
26.4
24.3
23.3
21.8
23.3
23
25.4
24.5
23.3
24.2
26.3
26.9
26.6
25.1
23.4
21.3
20.7
21.6
23.9
25.3
23.6
25.4
27.4
29.4
27.7
24.8
24.6
24.4
20.7
24.9
25.1
27.6
24.1
24.7
24.2
26.1
26.1
24.8
23.1
22.6
21.1
21.4
23.5
24
23.5
24.2
25.2
25.6
25.9
23.5
22.9
21.6
20.8
22.2
24.9
24.5
24.1
25.1
25.6
25.6
27.4
25.3
23.6
23.3
21.7
22.1
25.6
24.4
24.1
24.3
24.4
25.5
24.5
24.3
23.4
21.7
21.6
22.1
24.2
25.4
22.9
24.3
25.8
28.7
26.1
27
23.7
23.6
23.5
21.6
23.9
24.2
23.6
23.9
26.2
27
28
24.5
23.2
21.6
21.6
23
24.9
25.1
23.7
23.8
25
26.2
26.1
24.4
23.3
21.7
22.9
21.5
25
26.2
24.6
23.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you post your original data ? in a one column csv file. Using the ACF and PACF to identify the form of the ARIMA model requires , no pulses in the data , no level shifts in the data , no time trends in the data and no seasonal pulses in the data. Furthermore there in an implicit (to some and explicit to others !) assumption that the form of the model and parameters are invariant over time and that the residuals ( i.e. the y values adjusted for the ARIMA model and parameters ) have constant error variance. Non-constant error variance can arise from a linkage between Y and the error variance suggesting a power transform or a deterministic change at one or more points in time or even a time-varying error variance. Your data may have some of these "complications" or as I have often said some "opportunities" . The magnitude (if any) of one or more of these  complications can affect simple cutoff/decay analyses and of course severely impact any simple AIC/BIC approach no matter what some commentators preach or textbooks promote/say. Even advanced texts fail to mention these things as it often gets in the way of "selling the method" which is never a good thing (LOL).

My quick 2 cents is that you may have over-differenced .....

EDITED AFTER ANALYSIS OF DATA

I used one of my favorite toys (AUTOBOX) and obtained what appears to be a very reasonable model. I plotted the data [image] and AUTOBOX presented the ACF of the original series .[image] strongly suggesting monthly seasonality. There are two different kinds of models(causes) that can generate this symptom ; 1) a seasonal ARIMA model reflecting autoprojective structure AND 2) A regression type fixed effects model with 11 seasonal(monthly) dummies . Both of these models can also include level shifts and local time trends and pulse effects. AUTOBOX concluded a fairly exhaustive search process and concluded that the dominant model for this data was the latter. The final model yilded an Actual/Fit and Forecast graph of[image] and a graph of the forecasts here [image].

The model is presented here [image] and here [image] and here [image] relecting a hybrid of seasonal dummies , a level shift , pulses and an AR(1) component.

Thorough statsistical requires some validation that the model is sufficient thus we present a plot of the final residuals[image] and the ACF of the model errors [image] . All parameters are needed (statistically significant) and test for automatically selecting a power transform yielded negative results.

Hope this helps you. By the way meteorologists "know" that weather is strongly a seasonally deterministic ( month effects) series rather than an autoprojective model . Thus these results are what night have been exepected.

Finally my guess that you were over-differencing was correct becuase (in part) the non-stationarity was due to known fixed effects and the unknown upwards level shift (slight but significant) that was detected at period 182. Any clue what might have happened at or around period 182 (15 years = 2 months ) ?

Comment: i have included the data

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have no clue of what might have happened at period 182. Anyway am still a learner in this area of forecasting  but following your response are  you suggesting that regression fixed model is the best for my data an not ARIMA

Comment: Yes I think that your data is better suited for the regression fixed model approach .

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, i have learnt a lot from your explanation.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please upvote my answer and accept it so that others can become aware of your agreement with my analysis.

Comment: I would like to mention that your data set provides a major challenge to other software providers/approaches  and I would welcome any feedback from readers in this regard.

Comment: If I can help in the future I would be glad to . Thanks for accepting my answer. You can also up vote it .

Comment: @IrishStat, just to let you know: I think the user does not have sufficient reputation for upvoting.

Comment: ok   . I forgot about that .. tks .. Did you have any personal reflections on this  response  ? An alternative analysis ?